# What happen to a list when passed to a function?

Tags: python, list, function

I'm trying to understand how a list is treated when passed as an argument to a function. So what I did was the following:

I initialized a list:

```
ll = [1,2,3,4]
```

and define a function:

```
def Foo(ar):
    ar += [11]
```

I passed the list to the function:

```
Foo(ll)
```

and when I print it I got:

```
print ll # [1, 2, 3, 4, 11] #case(1)
```

So far so good.

Now I modified the function in order to reset the list such that it has a single element only:

```
def Foo(ar):
    ar = [11]
```

I recalled the syntax:

```
Foo(ll)
```

and when I reprint it, it resulted in the same list:

```
print ll # [1, 2, 3, 4] # case(2)
```

I thought the list was passed as reference; so whatever we do to the list inside a function will always change the original function passed from the main program. So for case(2) I was expecting the following result:

```
print ll # [11] # case(2) expected result
```

Am I missing something here?

Comment: `ar = [11]` assigns the name to a **completely different object**. If you want to replace the entire content of the list, try `ar[:] = [11]`.

Comment: I find you choosing of names and values (`ll` and `11`) disturbing...

Comment: I'm sorry for the choice of the names & values.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`ar += [11]` is **not** just an assignment. It's a method call (the method called is: `__iadd__`). when Python executes that line it calls the method and then assigns `ar` to the result. The `__iadd__` method of `list` *modifies* the current `list`.

`ar = [11]` is an *assignment* and hence it simply changes the value **of the local name `ar`**. But there is no link between the `ar` name inside the function and the value of the `ll` variable.

You probably want something like:

```
ar[:] = [11]
```

Comment: Strictly speaking, `ar += [11]` actually is still an assignment; it needs to be for things like `ar = (1, 2, 3); ar += (11,)` to work.

Comment: @user2357112 You're right, I was oversimplifying. Amended.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I think I got it now.

Comment: This is really what I need: ar[:] = [11]

Answer (score 5):

You have to make the difference between the *object* and the *name of the object*. Lists in Python are *mutable objects*, so they can be changed whenever you have a reference to it.

Names are just references to objects. Remember that technically in Python there are not variable, just names and objects, and objects are bound to names.

So, with that in mind, let's see your code:

```
def Foo1(ar):
    ar += [11]
```

This function takes a list, binds it to the local name `ar` and then modifies the list, adding a new value.

However this other code:

```
def Foo2(ar):
    ar = [11]
```

This function takes a list, bound to the `ar` name, and then rebinds the name `ar` to a new list with one value. The original object is unmodified and fogotten, inside this function.

Then when you do:

```
a = [1,2,3]
```

And then call:

```
Foo1(a)
```

that modifies the list adding a new value, but:

```
Foo2(a)
```

does nothing to the value of `a`.

If you want to write a function that replaces all the content of the list with another, you can do that with:

```
def Foo3(a):
    a[:] = [11]
```

This code does not rebind `a` but modifies the list by replacing the content with the new list.

To further illustrate my point, look at this example:

```
a = []
b = []
c = a
a.append(1)
b.append(2)
c.append(3)
print a
print b
print c
```

It will print:

```
[1, 3]
[2]
[1, 3]
```

Can you to tell why?

Comment: Is it because the names a & c are now used to refer to the same object?
Thanks btw for the explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Augmented assignments like `+=` do something that normal `=` assignment doesn't do. When you assign to a name, like so:

```
ar = [11]
```

that's an operation on the `ar` name. The list object that `ar` previously referred to is unchanged, so when you do `print ll` outside the function, you see the original list.

When you do

```
ar += [11]
```

that's not quite equivalent to

```
ar = ar + [11]
```

If you did `ar = ar + [11]`, `ll` would be unchanged. However, `+=` requests that if possible, the list that `ar` refers to should perform the operation by modifying its own state, rather than by creating a new list. Since lists are mutable, the list modifies itself to have a new `11` element, and this change is visible through the `ll` variable.